Jupyter opening to and gets stuck on a local file instead of localhost
I'm on MacOS Sonoma 14.4, Python 3.10.14. When I run

jupyter lab

A new window is automatically opened into my browser at the following link:
file:///Users/username/Library/Jupyter/runtime/jpserver-18425-open.html
The page sits here stuck and does not load Jupyter, only displaying the text "This page should redirect you to a Jupyter application. If it doesn't, click here to go to Jupyter."

If I manually enter http://localhost:8888 or http://localhost:8888/lab into the search, I am not loaded to the normal Jupyter window either. Using the jupyter notebook command instead of jupyter lab brings me to the same issue. I have been trying to find a solution but so far have come shorthanded. How can I get Jupyter to normally load up?
To provide potentially related context, I earlier uninstalled and reinstalled Python for unrelated reasons, and during the uninstallation I deleted all Python packages according to the instructions from answers to another question on the site.

You might want to check out JupyterLab Desktop here. It is one of the easiest ways to install Jupyter. But read the reading material I link to as it uses a particular project management style that you'll want to adopt if you choose to use it. Please, only use current posts about installing things on Macs. That link you have at the end of you post started from 2012 and not relevant to your situation. Current Macs are a very unique thing relative to coding set ups.

Another good choice is installing the Anaconda Distribution on your Mac as it will handle most things if you access Jupyter and Python through the Anaconda Navigator after you install that. That product though is a bit fancier and so you should read and follow the Getting Started material to learn about using conda to manage environments.
